# How to display all the items in textfile in a listbox in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a listbox to list the account names that are in users.conf textfile.

How can I list it for choosing a account to delete ?

- Users.conf:
- 56185     User-Password == "56185"
- 40317     User-Password == "40317"
- 11581     User-Password == "11581"
- 38467     User-Password == "38467"
- 50071     User-Password == "50071"
- 81045     User-Password == "81045"
- Preferred Output in listbox:
- 56185
- 40317
- 11581
- 38467
- 50071
- 81045

  ```
  def deleteuser():
     with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r") as fh:
      lines = fh.readlines()
     with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "w") as fh:
      for line in lines:                  
          if deleteuserentry.get() in line and  deleteuserpwd.get() == "Pa$$w0rd123" :
             tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Account Deleted")
             end()


      deleteteuser = ttk.Label(page1, text="Delete User").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')
      deleteusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter current user's username:").grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='W')
      deleteuserentry = ttk.Listbox(page1, selectmode = BROWSE)
      deleteuserentry.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=2)
      for lines in ('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r"):
          lb.insert(END,line)
      deleteuserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter Administrator's password:").grid(column=0, row=8, sticky='W')
      deleteuserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1, show='*')
      deleteuserpwd.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=2)
      deleteuserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Delete this User', borderwidth=2, command= deleteuser)
       deleteuserconfirm.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky='W')
      du = Button(page1, text='import file to delete multiple accounts', borderwidth=2, command= du)
      du.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky='E')
  ```

Comment: Do you want to delete the entry from the file or just from the list box?

Comment: Delete from the text file

Answer (score 0):

You could match the line via regex, picking the user id at the start and the line data the populating it into a list. When an item is deleted from the listbox then the user id is appended into another list. And when the interface is closed the actual operation of deleting from the file happens. Here is a structure of what I mean. You can use it as an example - optimising where need be.

```
import re
import os
from tkinter import *

pattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)\s')
data_file = 'users.conf'
res_file = 'result.conf'  # This could alse be the same file from which the users are read

try:
    os.remove(res_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

# Read users
with open(data_file) as f:
    lines = []

    for l in f.readlines():
        match = pattern.match(l)
        if match is not None:
            user_id = match.group('user_id')
        else:
            user_id = ''
        lines.append((user_id, l))


lines_to_remove = []


def delete_record(lb):
    user_id = lb.get(ANCHOR)
    lines_to_remove.append(user_id)
    lb.delete(ANCHOR)


# Display GUI
top = Tk()
lb = Listbox(top)
b = Button(top, text="Delete",
           command=lambda lb=lb: delete_record(lb))

for line in lines:
    if line[1]:
        lb.insert(END, line[0])

lb.pack()
b.pack()
top.mainloop()

# Delete lines
valid_lines = filter(lambda l: l[0] not in lines_to_remove, lines)
with open(res_file, 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines([l[1] for l in valid_lines])
```